# how to save data by disabled text box?

Tags: jquery, jsp, textbox

In my jsp page, 1 checkbox, 2 textbox and 1 submit button. The checkbox is used for enabling and disabling the text box. Data saved when textbox is enable but not saved when textbox is disable.

following code is for toggle.

```
function toggleFields(status){
    if (status==false){
        $("#textbox1").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#textbox2").removeAttr("disabled");
        } 
        else {
        $("#textbox1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#textbox2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }       
}
```

please help me in this.

Comment: Have you tried getting the values of textbox with `$("#textbox1").val()`?

Comment: Do not just focus on the text box behavior if it was disabled or enabled, just validate the check box, if the check box was check then it will be saved otherwise not.

Comment: @Nesmar, yes when checkbox is checked then it will be saved otherwise not. what to do now?

Comment: @JitendraKhedar That answers your problem, I mean if the checkbox returns true then it will execute your code to save the data otherwise it will do nothing even how many clicks on the submit button. Get It?

Comment: @Nesmar, ok get it, can u give me solution ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `readonly` instead of `disabled`.

```
 $("#textbox1").attr("readonly", true);
```

Your code would be

```
function toggleFields(status){
    if (status==false){
        $("#textbox1").attr("readonly", false);
        $("#textbox2").attr("readonly", false);
        } 
        else {
        $("#textbox1").attr("readonly", true);
        $("#textbox2").attr("readonly", true);
    }       
}
```

Comment: is it else condition ..what to write in if condition?

Comment: Check my updated answer there was an error i guess, if it does not work, try making a fiddle